# Prompt user for (meta)data on file upload

Tags: document-library, spfx, list-form, modern-document-library

**[context]**
I am working with sharepoint online, using modern views. i have a webpage with a document library attached.

**[goal]**
I would like to prompt a user to fill out all required (meta)data about a document when they upload a document to the document library.

**[faced issues]**
Many solutions I find online are either for older SP-versions or already outdated custom web parts. But without proper documentation (proper != microsoft documentation) about spfx I'm not getting much further by adjusting these webparts.

I'm open to any form of solution.

*[if more info is required please do tell]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is missing from the modern experience, We have developed our own upload web part where we control the upload behavior

- which fields are required
- what type of files (.docx, .pdf) can be uploaded to library.

What you could do alternatively you could create an Flow that would prompt user to enter the missing metadata.

Comment: Thanks for replying!  could you elaborate a bit on   "you could create an Flow that would prompt user to enter the missing metadata."  ? I do not understand how this could be done using Flow.

Comment: when item is created, or on a schedule basis you could iterate through items. Find the ones that are missing metadata and send an email to the creator of the item to update it.

Comment: this is a great idea, thanks for all your help!